# multiple requests in a single HttpConnection in android?

Tags: android, httpclient

the [Apache guide](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d4e582) on Http connections mention that

> The overhead of connection handshaking can be significant, especially
>   for small HTTP messages. One can achieve a much higher data throughput
>   if open connections can be re-used to execute multiple requests.

What i want to do is, i want to send 20 similar post request (i.e. the same headers), but the data i send with it is pretty small. So with every request i'm sending the same header data again and again.So i'm looking for a workaround.

for eg:

- establish a connection(sending and using the header info, ONCE)
- send 20 post requests
- close the connection.

My Question : Is it, or is it not, possible to achieve that using [Android's `HttpClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/.../http/client/HttpClient.html)? If Yes, please provide/point me to a lesson/tutorial/example.

Thanks in advance.

PS: i did some research, couldn't quite find anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*— Edited —*

I'm sorry I misunderstood your question.

What you want is obviously possible. However, I think it's up to the server side. If you code server then you can control the format of messages between client and server. If not, then perhaps you should follow server's APIs.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i do know the apache-android http client thing :-).. I edited the question, gave some details, please check. just make sure  if that is what you understood from the question? if yes 
 Can you explain what you've done here?  `setDefaultMaxPerRoute` & `setMaxTotal` do what?

Comment: I'm sorry, after checking the documentation, I see `setDefaultMaxPerRoute()` and `setMaxTotal()` are not available in Android. I edited my answer.

Comment: i have access to the server, but have very limited knowledge in that area. Can you please specify an approach?

Comment: I have an old project (not yet finished) [here](http://goo.gl/QRC5u) (please download it as I serve that document only in some hours). Please note that prototype is very basic and un-secure. For better information, you can refer to others, such as [Twitter APIs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs), [Flickr APIs](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/)…